# "Can't connect to MySQL server", despite connection working on test

Tags: php, mysql, database, jotform

I have the following `thankyou.php` stored in my `public_html` folder on 000webhost server, along with the MySQL database to which I want to connect. The page is a form, which is embedded from jotform, on submit I want the answers to post to MySQL database.

I have tested the code a million times, it appears to run fine but I still get the error:

> Thankyou for entering your sales details Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql6.000webhost.com' (4)

I have created a further test.php to test the connect and it comes up with connection made. Do you think it is a problem with jotform? I have read other users have managed to get the connection to work, so I am thinking it is maybe a problem with mysql6000webhost?

```
<?php
$fullname = $_POST['clientmanager'];

print "<p><p>";

print " Thankyou $fullname for entering your sales details";


// This function will run within each post array including multi-dimensional arrays 
function ExtendedAddslash(&$params)
{ 
        foreach ($params as &$var) {
            // check if $var is an array. If yes, it will start another ExtendedAddslash() function to loop to each key inside.
            is_array($var) ? ExtendedAddslash($var) : $var=addslashes($var);
        }
}

// Initialize ExtendedAddslash() function for every $_POST variable
ExtendedAddslash($_POST);      

$submission_id = $_POST['submission_id']; 
$formID = $_POST['formID'];
$IP = $_POST['ip'];
$Placement = $_POST['selectplacement4'];
$Client_Name= $_POST['name7'];
$Client_Address= $_POST['address'][0] ."-". $_POST['address'][1]."-". $_POST['address'][2]."-". $_POST['address'][3]."-". $_POST['address'][4]."-". $_POST['address'][5];
$Client_Phone= $_POST['phonenumber'][0] ."-". $_POST['phonenumber'][1];
$Attn_Name1= $_POST['name'];
$Attn_Email1= $_POST['email15'];
$Attn_Name2= $_POST['name2'];
$Attn_Email2= $_POST['email2'];
$Candidate_Name= $_POST['candidatename'];
$Position= $_POST['position'];
$Start_Date= $_POST['startdate'][0] ."-". $_POST['startdate'][1]."-". $_POST['startdate'][2];
$frequency= $_POST['frequency'];
$rate= $_POST['rate24'];
$Units= $_POST['noof'];
$Salary= $_POST['salary'];
$feepercent= $_POST['fee'];
$Reason= $_POST['input33'];
$feeamt= $_POST['feeamt'];
$RecruiterName= $_POST['recruitername'];
$NewRecName= $_POST['entername'];
$RecruiterPercent= $_POST['recruiter'];
$ClientMgrName= $_POST['clientmanager'];
$ClientMgrPercent= $_POST['clientmanager36'];
$TotalFeePercent= $_POST['associatefees37'];
$TotalFee= $_POST['associatefees'];


$db_host = 'mysql6.000webhost.com';
$db_username = 'a8748341_blt';
$db_password = '******';
$db_name = 'a8748341_bltrec';

mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name); 

// search submission ID

$query = "SELECT * FROM bltrecruiting where submission_id = $submission_id";
$sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
$resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);

if ($resultcount > 0) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE `bltrecruiting` SET 
                                `Placement` = '$Placement',
                                `Client_Name` = '$Client_Name',
                                `Client_Address` = '$Client_Address',
                                `Client_Phone` = '$Client_Phone',
                                `Attn_Name1` = '$Attn_Name1',
                                `Attn_Email1` = '$Attn_Email1',
                                `Attn_Name2` = '$Attn_Name2',
                                `Attn_Email2` = '$Attn_Email2'

                             WHERE `submission_id` = '$submission_id'") 
     or die(mysql_error());

} else {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bltrecruiting` (submission_id, formID, IP, Placement, Client_Name, Client_Address, Client_Phone, Attn_Name1, Attn_Email1, Attn_Name2, Attn_Email2, Candidate_Name, Position, Start_Date, frequency, rate, Units, Salary, feepercent, Reason, feeamt, RecruiterName, NewRecName, RecruiterPercent, ClientMgrName, ClientMgrPercent, TotalFeePercent, TotalFee) 
                               VALUES ('submission_id, formID, IP, Placement, Client_Name, Client_Address, Client_Phone, Attn_Name1, Attn_Email1, Attn_Name2, Attn_Email2, Candidate_Name, Position, Start_Date, frequency, rate, Units, Salary, feepercent, Reason, feeamt, RecruiterName, NewRecName, RecruiterPercent, ClientMgrName, ClientMgrPercent, TotalFeePercent, TotalFee) ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

}
?>
```

Comment: Hint: `VALUES ('submission_id, formID, IP, Placement, Client_Name, Client_Address, Client_Phone, Attn_Name1, Attn_Email1, Attn_Name2, Attn_Email2, Candidate_Name, Position, Start_Date, frequency, rate, Units, Salary, feepercent, Reason, feeamt, RecruiterName, NewRecName, RecruiterPercent, ClientMgrName, ClientMgrPercent, TotalFeePercent, TotalFee)` + http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The `ExtendedAddslash()` function does not make your user input safe, so it is worth switching to a library that offers parameterisation before you begin fixing this. You will then not have to worry about quoting values in your SQL, since the engine will do it for you - and you will be safe(r) from crackers too.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii, thanks for your speedy response, so do you believe the problem is not the connection it's the syntax in the query I am running?

Comment: This too `mysql_numrows` missing an underscore. Try `mysqli_` method instead.

Comment: I think @Fred's point was that you put an apostrophe in the query, which would be right for strings, but not for integers. I would guess `submission_id` is an integer. In any case, you only have one apostrophe, and they are usually used in pairs (they _delimit_ a string, beginning and end).

Comment: @halfer thank you, which library would you recommend?

Comment: PDO or MySQLi are the replacements. I prefer PDO (I am of the opinion that getting data out of it is easier) but either is good.

Comment: [**Use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: @halfer okay thank you, in case you couldn't tell I am just learning this, I am trying!! do you think I should change submission_id to a string query? or is it not that simple

Comment: If you use parameterisation then you don't need to worry about types, the engine will do it for you. See the examples on the links that Fred has provided.

Comment: okay,  I guess I will have to read documentation on mysqli as I have no clue on how to change the code

Comment: okay thank you for your time I really do appreciate it

Comment: It would seem your query is never reached as the script errors out when you try to connect to the database. Are you sure the user as access from any host and not just localhost? From where did you test the connection with your test script?

Comment: hi @jeroen, I tested the connection from my browser, through the so the url is http://recruitingblt.comli.com/testconnect.php, it is working it reads Connected successfully (please ignore my previous comment - I had changed the password in an attempt to get this to work and had not updated my testconnection.php file). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your insert query VALUES looks strange to me:
one opening single quote never closed,
no use of the php variables you intialize some lines above...

Maybe you mean something like

```
VALUES ('$submission_id', '$formID', '$IP', '$Placement', ...., '$TotalFeePercent', '$TotalFee')
```

Comment: I hadn't paid enough attention to the reported error message, it's a connection problem (you'll face request problems later :-) ). Have you tried to copy your $dbhost and so on values and paste them to phpmyadmin connection form, to check that there's no problem on that side?

Comment: Hi @fpierrat, thank you for your time. I have a testconnection.php file yes with $dbvalues, and when I open the url http://www.recruitingblt.comli.com/testconnect.php in my broser it says connection successful. Is that what you mean?> I will try adding $ and ' in VALUES line now. Thanks again

Comment: Sure that all the $db_... variables and the mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() are exactly the same in your test.php? Same encoding also for both script, not one in utf8 and one in iso or smthg like that?

Comment: Exactly the same, I've edited the code a little now and run an error report, the only error im getting after fixing syntax is                               Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'                     the end of my code now looks like this;              else {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bltrecruiting` (submission_id, formID, IP, Placement, Client_Name)
                               VALUES ('$submission_id', '$formID', '$ip', '$selectplacement4', '$name7') ")

}

?>              do i need to do something else to exit? thanks @fpierrat

Comment: you should also try `echo($query);`, for all of the queries present in your script, to see what you're really trying to send to mysql... maybe a post variable went wrong, or is not set at all, or dates come out in an unwanted text format or whatever...

Comment: also replace your `or die(mysql_error());` with `or die("-A-".mysql_error());` , `or die("-B-".mysql_error());` and `or die("-C-".mysql_error());` so you can identifie which call brings the error message.

Comment: if an error states theres a problem with syntax in the final line (line87) and thats the only error now, I think this means it is now connecting .... do you think there could still be a problem with one of the calls? @fpierrat or just how I am closing the script? It says there are too many } but I can;t see why